# JavaScript For Numbers

Tags: javascript

could you please tell me why is it used

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (topNumber - bottomNumber + 1)) + bottomNumber;
```

Please share your best teaching cause I am new beginner

```
  var input1 = prompt("Please type a starting number");
    var bottomNumber = parseInt(input1);
    var input = prompt("Please type a number");
    var topNumber = parseInt(input);
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (topNumber - bottomNumber + 1)) + bottomNumber;
    var message = "<p>" + randomNumber + "  is a number between  " + bottomNumber + " and " + topNumber + ".</p>";
    document.write(message);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's unpack it from the inside out:

- [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) gives a floating-point number between 0 and 1 (including 0, but not including 1). For example, 0.26254851654.
- `(topNumber - bottomNumber + 1)` gives the number of different integers between `bottomNumber` and `topNumber`, including both of those themselves. Why `+ 1`? Well, to find the number of integers between 5 and 10 for example: 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. There are 10 - 5 + 1 = 6 of them, not 5. Let's call this `numNumbers`.
- Multiply these two together, so we get a floating point number between 0 and `numNumbers` (still including 0 but not `numNumbers` itself).
- We want an integer (whole number), so we round it down with [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor). We now have an integer in the range `0, 1, ..., numNumbers - 1` (remember, the floating point number could get close to `numNumbers`, but never becomes equal, so `numNumbers` is not part of this range). Each of these is equally likely.
- Add `bottomNumber` to end up with an integer in the range `bottomNumber, bottomNumber + 1, ..., bottomNumber + numNumbers - 1`. But what is `bottomNumber + numNumbers - 1`? It's exactly `topNumber`! So we now have an integer in the range `bottomNumber, ..., topNumber`, exactly what we needed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `randomNumber` builds a random number between to numbers (a range). Being `topNumber` the max and `bottomNumber` the min in the range. For clarity:

```
const max = 10;
const min = 0;
const example = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is overcomplicated for a beginner (sorry if you not a beginner) the Math.random() method returns a random number between 0 and 1 but if you want a random number between 0 and a specific number you have to use
`Math.floor(Math.random() * x + 1)` and "x" is the specific number